# Flutter pull to refresh not working properly

Tags: flutter

I have implemented pull refreshing function using **Flutter webview** plugin. Pull to refresh is working just fine but the problem is that once I just try it and then next time whenever I touch on any other part of the screen within an app it auto refreshes even if I don't do any pull to refresh sliding. Here is my main code:

```
late int scheck;
late WebViewController controllerGlobal;
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     
       initialRoute: '/',

    routes: {
      '/home': (context) => WebViewEx(), 
       '/': (context) => LoadScreen(), 
    
    },
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewEx extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
}

class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewEx> {
  late bool check, check1;
  late ScrollController _scrollController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
    check = false;
    check1 = false;
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset <=
            _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      controllerGlobal.reload();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          await controllerGlobal.goBack();
          return Future.value(true);

        }, 
        child: ListView(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            Container(
              //padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://doorstep.pro/user/login',
                gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                gestureRecognizers: [
                  Factory(() => PlatformViewVerticalGestureRecognizer(kind: null)),
                ].toSet(),
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  setState(() {
                    bool temp = check;
                    check = true;
                    if (!temp) controllerGlobal.scrollBy(0, 10);
                  });
                },
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  controllerGlobal = webViewController;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  goBack() {}
}

class PlatformViewVerticalGestureRecognizer
    extends VerticalDragGestureRecognizer {
  PlatformViewVerticalGestureRecognizer({ PointerDeviceKind? kind})
      : super(kind: kind);

  Offset _dragDistance = Offset.zero;

  @override
  void addPointer(PointerEvent event) {
    startTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    _dragDistance = _dragDistance + event.delta;
    controllerGlobal.getScrollY().then((value) {
      print(value);
      if (value < 5) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg:  "Refreshing...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 179, 158, 157),
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
    );
        controllerGlobal.reload();
      }
    });
    // if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
    //   final double dy = _dragDistance.dy.abs();
    //   final double dx = _dragDistance.dx.abs();

    //   if (dy > dx && dy > kTouchSlop) {
    //     // vertical drag - accept
    //     resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
    //     _dragDistance = Offset.zero;
    //   } else if (dx > kTouchSlop && dx > dy) {
    //     // horizontal drag - stop tracking
    //     stopTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
    //     _dragDistance = Offset.zero;
    //   }
    // }
  }

  @override
  String get debugDescription => 'horizontal drag (platform view)';

  @override
  void didStopTrackingLastPointer(int pointer) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this in your dispose method.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, it's still reloading whenever I click on any part of the screen